# Helper SQL function in Node

Tags: sql, node.js

I am trying to understand code of someone code where he have created custom helper function for SQL

Here is the relevant code where he used it

```
exports.getCommission = function(conn, o, type) {
    let table = "order_commissions";
    if (type == "live") {
      table = "order_commissions_live";
    }

    let sql = `select o.*, p.title, p.first_name, p.middle_name, p.last_name from ${table} o left join distributor_geneology dg on (o.fcid=dg.fcid) left join profile p on (p.user_id=dg.user_id) where o.order_no=?  order by ledger_type, for_rank`;

    return DatabaseHelper.getSql(conn, sql, [o.order_no]);
}
```

Here conn is sql connection which the person pass from the other route

Let it be: `let conn = mysql.mysqlConnection();`

Now DataBaseHelper where the magic happens (and the function) I am unable to comprehend is this

```
function getSql(connection, sql, params, rowno) {
    var dfd = Q.defer();
    connection.query(sql, params, function(err, res) {     
      if (err) {
        return dfd.reject(err);
      }
      console.log("abc" + res)
      if (typeof rowno == 'undefined')
        return dfd.resolve(res);
      if (!res.length){ 
        return dfd.reject(new Error("No rows found"));
      }
      if (!res[rowno]) {  
        return dfd.reject(new Error("No row found"));
      }
      return dfd.resolve(res[rowno]);
    });
    return dfd.promise;
  }
```

**[Question]** Can someone help me understand the flow here? Like  how the function getSql work here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, I can walk you through it:

```
function getSql(connection, sql, params, rowno) {
    // This line uses the Q library to setup a Promise, which is an alternative async control approach to callbacks (the Nodejs default approach)
    var dfd = Q.defer();

    // Take the provided connection and start a query. The anonymous function here is the callback expected by the library's connection.query() function signature
    connection.query(sql, params, function(err, res) {    
      // nodejs callbacks usually use the error-first standard, so if err exists (i.e. null will return false in the 'if' statement), we reject the Promise with the error.  The calling code will need to handle it with the .catch() function.
      if (err) {
        return dfd.reject(err);
      }
      // just a stdout log statement. 
      console.log("abc" + res)

      // rowno is apparently intended to be an optional parameter to the getSql function.  If it's undefined, we just want to resolve the Promise and send the calling code the full query response.  That'll be passed to the .then() function on the Promise.  
      if (typeof rowno == 'undefined')
        return dfd.resolve(res);

      // I don't actually agree that this should return an error, but the author is saying that if the query returns no results, it should be an error rather than just an empty array.  So again we Reject the Promise to send an error.  
      if (!res.length){ 
        return dfd.reject(new Error("No rows found"));
      }
      // If we get here, then we know that both there are rows and the calling code wanted a specific row.  This check is seeing if the rowno (row number) exists in the result set.  Again, throwing an error if not (which, again, to me isn't an error). 
      if (!res[rowno]) {  
        return dfd.reject(new Error("No row found"));
      }
      // If we get here, we Resolve the Promise and pass the .then() function the requested row. 
      return dfd.resolve(res[rowno]);
    });

    // This is *outside* that anonymous function (the callback from the query call), and what you're doing is passing the calling code the actual Promise object so that it can chain the .then() and the .catch(). 
    return dfd.promise;
  }
```

Ok, so given all that,  you'd call it something like this:

```
getCommission(conn, o, type).then(results => {
   console.log(results); // or however you want to handle the results
}).then(e => {
   console.error(e); // or however you want to handle an error.
});
```

All that said, the example code is *pretty bad* in my opinion.  To start with the string interpolation he's using is potentially a nasty SQL injection vector, and as well I mentioned how some of the error things are a bit odd.